# There is no sbt window tool in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have followed the instructions https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sbt-tool-window.html#sbt_tool_window
I have installed plugin `scala`, restart IDE and then the window tool for sbt should appear in `View -> Tool windows -> sbt` but this is missing.

Without this I have no possibility to reload the scala project after library depdendcies changed.

I have the newest version 2020.2.3.

Comment: Did you try to import the project from the sbt file? Does it work?

Comment: It crashes than... well I have created this project from the begining and now sbt tool appeared.